# Make UIwebView 100% screen size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

How can I make this code for a UIwebView 100% height and width?

```
  UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024,768)];
    NSString *url=@"http://www.google.com";
    NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
    [webview loadRequest:nsrequest];
    [self.view addSubview:webview];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make your frame use your current view's self.frame.size.width & self.view.frame.size.height instead of 1024 & 768.

```
UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

Comment: so how do I change my code? (I am a beginner at objective c)

Comment: also, what's the code for no UIwebView bouncing, the codes I find on here don't work for me

Comment: @PHPWebDev101 - the site provides a way to say "thanks so much, it worked" which is the little check mark to the left of the answer.  UIWebView descends from scroll view which has a `bounces` property that can be set to `NO`